# Django: Redirecting to previous, specific page

Tags: django, python-3.x, url, redirect, button

Good evening,

inside my Django-Table there is a button that redirects to another page to edit the entry inside a row. So - let's say - in my url: ".../coworker/3/" I press a random button inside my table and it leads me to the next side (url: "../coworker/3/...something.../"). My Question is: is it possible to press another button to abort and redirect to the previous page?
Right now I'm having trouble with the  inside my url!

Error message:
"NoReverseMatch at ..."

The button that leads me from one page to another (the one that's working):

```
<td>{{ item.id }}</td>
<td>{{ item.customer }}</td>
<td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" href="{% url '...something...' item.id %}">Edit</a></td>
```

Thanks and a good night to all of you!

Answer (score 0):

NoReverseMatch is a Django exception that is raised when a URL cannot be matched against any string or regular express in your URL configuration.

Answer (score 0):

So, I really made this more compicated than it was...

I solved my problem by passing on the pk (in this case the id of the selected coworker) and used the same line of code from above:

```
<a href="{% url 'Coworker' coworker_id %}" class="btn btn-outline-light" role="button">Abort</a>
```